# Pandas self-conditional column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I am trying to create a column in pandas that is conditional to it's previous value along with other columns.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = np.random.standard_normal(100)
A = pd.DataFrame(a)
A['Out'] = 0
A['Out2'] = 0
for t in range(1,A.shape[0]):
    if (A[0][t] > 1) & (A['Out'][t-1]==0):
        A['Out'][t] = 1
    elif (A[0][t] < -1) & (A['Out'][t-1]==0):
        A['Out'][t] = -1
    elif ((A[0][t] > 0) & (A['Out'][t-1]==-1)) | ((A[0][t] < 0) & (A['Out'][t-1]==1)):
        A['Out'][t] = 0
    else:
        A['Out'][t] = A['Out'][t-1] 
A['Out2'] = np.where((A.index== 0),0
        ,np.where((A[0] > 1) & (A['Out2'].shift()==0), 1
        ,np.where((A[0] < -1) & (A['Out2'].shift()==0), -1
        ,np.where(((A[0] > 0) & (A['Out2'].shift()==-1)) | ((A[0] < 0) & (A['Out2'].shift()==1)), 0
        ,A['Out2'].shift()))))
```

The column A['Out2'] tries to copy A['Out'] in a vectorized form but does not read the previous values. Column A['Out'] takes too long to compile through a loop. Can someone help me with a faster, vectorized approach to creating this column?

Comment: Can you provide your desired output and an example input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function and then use apply. To access the previous data you can use a variable to store that value. Hope the following code helps.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = np.random.standard_normal(100)
A = pd.DataFrame(a)
state = 0
def get_val(A,prev_state):
    global state
    if (A > 1) & (prev_state==0):
        state = 1
    elif (A < -1) & (prev_state==0):
        state = -1
    elif ((A > 0) & (prev_state==-1)) | ((A < 0) & (prev_state==1)):
        state = 0     
    return state

A['Out'] = A[0].apply(lambda x: get_val(x,state))
```

Output :

```
           0  Out 
0  1.366864    1     
1  0.887763    1     
2 -0.663636    0     
3 -1.824950   -1     
4  0.459663    0    
5 -1.325129   -1     
6  1.587188    0    
7 -0.148159    0     
8  0.578862    0     
9  0.758460    0
```

If you use `%%timeit`

```
100 loops, best of 3: 2.16 ms per loop
```

Comment: This is perfect... Thanks for the quick response!!

Comment: You're welcome @random_black. Dont forget to upvote when you get enough reputation